# A SQL with incorrect syntax does not thrown an error in MariaDB Server version: 10.1.45?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
select distinct search_text,language, input_encode 
from visitors 
where unique_id='njZ3AWt7vmLcrGC2uOqnCplkm' 
order by visitors_id desc 
limit 9;
```

The above SQL is invalid. I get the following error when I run it on **MySql Server version: 8.0.19**

> Your Recent searches:Error: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'visitors.visitors_id' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT.

Makes sense.

But, when I execute the same SQL on **Server version: 10.1.45-MariaDB** guess what happens?

I get a result set. Can anyone explain how this could be?

[image]

Comment: New Flash! mariaDB and MySQL are no longer the same beast

Comment: Check the manual for parameters in the `sql_mode` specifically `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`

Comment: MariaDB started as a clone of MySQL but nowadays has different features. They are becoming increasingly different.

Comment: Please provide (1) the full text of the error, and (2) `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (so I can experiment).

Comment: I was able to resolve this by removing ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY fro sql_mode SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));